# Houseparty App streaming technology

Tags: ios, live-streaming

Anyone know what streaming technology or methodology the Houseparty app uses to ensure that there's no lag between guests' streams?

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/houseparty-group-video-chat/id1065781769?mt=8&_branch_match_id=328927036209051924

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Houseparty uses WebRTC as it's base technology and currently uses Tokbox, a provider of video/audio WebRTC services.

Latency should be typically ~ 300 msec between parties plus any network latency. Typically anything < 500 msec delay is not perceivable by small group conversation.

Comment: It'd be more helpful if the source or credibility of the answerer is cited.